# How to pipe the output of s3 cp to unzip?

Tags: shell, pipe, unzip, aws-cli

I want to unzip a file from s3 without saving the archive. I'm not sure how to complete this command, or if unzip is the best option. Guidance would be appreciated

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.zip - | unzip ??
```

Comment: Unzip currently doesn't support reading and extracting from the standard input (pipe): http://www.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html#Future . Funzip supports reading from _stdin_, but extracts only the first file from the archive.

Comment: Sadly, I think there's no solution to your question, unless `file.zip` only contains a single file. Other formats like `7z` and `tar` can be extracted from a stream, but `zip` is limited in that regard.